# POST data over HTTPS is secure enough?

Tags: post, ssl, https

I have a page where i need to send parameter (say param1) via post and site is running
over HTTPS, would it be secure can anyone hack this information, what is the correct
solution to send info over https ?

Below is the JSP page, indeed the info is send via HTTPS but user can see view source to
see value of param1 and param2, would we use some encryption standard or jsp taglib so
that user is not able to view source ass well as not able to read param1 and param2 values.

### testPage.jsp

```
This is a parent page , in this a second jsp is included


<form id="myForm" target="iframe" method="post"   action="http://www.abc.com/jsp/dGrid.jsp">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="77"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="SS"/>
</form>

<iframe name="iframe" width="1500px" scrolling="no" height="1170px" frameborder="0"   allowtransparency="">
</iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: You will have to define what you see as "hacking" before. You seem to be worried about the actual user manipulating values before sending them - so, yes, encryption or a checksum could secure that. But do these values have to go to the client and from there back to the server at all - can't you just put them into as session and read them back from there on the next page?

Comment: Thanks CBro, the values could not be kept in session because in this case we have a parent page which belongs to another company and inside that page an iframe is embeded which contains URL of our application and which accepts parameters param1 and param2. In that case what would be the ideal solution ?  Both the  applications which is parent and child resides in same machine ..

Comment: _“In that case what would be the ideal solution ?”_ – solution to _what specific problem?_

Comment: to pass the param1 and param2 values securely so that i can't be easily hacked.